# angularjs "ng-view" in asp.net mvc application - routing

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

i'm working at the moment on a web application, that uses asp.net with mvc and angularjs. The problem is, to get angularjs with an "ng-view" in a cshtml site. 
I didn't worked with angularjs and mvc before, so I hope you can help me :-)

Thats my problem:

- Angularjs works with the litle test {{1+2}},
- but it didn't displays me the routing from other cshtml sites.

Profile.cshtml

```
{{1+2}}
<div ng-view></div>
```

For further questions: there is no  body oder html tag, because i defined it in the _layout.cshtml. In this site I also integrated the script of angularjs across BundleConfig.cs. Angularjs still works on Profile.cshmtl with the {{1+2}} test.

The Profile.cshtml should show the _PProfiles.cshtml site with the following code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="profileFilter" placeholder="Suchen..." />
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4">Employee Table</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="employee in employeeList | filter: searchFilter">
                <td><a href="#/_PProfiles/{{employee.Identifier}}">{{employee.firstName}} {{employee.lastName}}</a></td>
                <td>{{employee.emailAdress}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.Org1}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.Org2}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.Org3}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And the app.js (angularjs script) should route this:
(there is also a further webpage, with should displayed, when I typed something in the input tag --> searchFilter)

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('Headcount', [
    'Headcount.controller',
    'Headcount.service',
    'ngRoute'
    ]).

    config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider.

          when("/_PProfiles", {
              templateUrl: "/Home/_PProfiles.cshtml",
              controller: "tableController"
          }).
          when("/_PProfiles/:id", {
              templateUrl: "/Home/_PEmployees.cshtml", 
              controller: "employeeController"
          }).
          otherwise({ redirectTo: '/Profiles' });
    }]);

})();
```

The Profile.cshtml site is implemented in the Home:Controller and is displayed when I run the application. 
The other site _PProfile.cshtml is not implemented.

HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace myApplikation.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Profile()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your profile page.";
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Departments()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your departments page.";

            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

**This all works in a normal asp.net application without mvc.** 
I think the problem can be in the mvc routing, because it doesnt allows angularjs to route.

**EDIT:** That problem is solved (it depends on false integration with the mvc view), but ng-view still doesn't displays anything.
**Note:** I'm working with angular 1.5.9. With the higher versions, the ng-view doesn't work without the mvc controller.

So are there any suggestions to solve this problem?

**Edit 09.07.18**
Here you can see the output in the browser console.

[Image_ng-view&ng-controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvOYL.png)

ng-view is commented and displays nothing. The element above displays a message with

> $scope.Message = "Test if it works"

This was a test, if the controller works.

And when I scope the {{employeeList}} from the "tableController" it also works. 
But not the ng-view!
[Image_ng-controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOcxL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of ng-view:

https://next.plnkr.co/plunk/Pp0ACPzJwc9x85XwPAVU

As per your question, the angualrJs will not work with MVC controller. 
So better way is to use angular with asp.net webApi controller. You need to get rid of ASP.net MVC controller, ASP.net MVC routing and ASP.net MVC views(i.e .cshtml files).

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/826307/AngularJS-With-MVC-Web-API : This will help you to organize your angular app.

I will suggest you to first convert .cshtml files to .html. Keep in an app folder and make the initial file load to index.html. Just use angular routing which will take care of rendering your html files.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But I think, it have to work with an mvc controller. 

Angularjs still works here, only the ng-view doesn't work. When I scope messages this also works.  So this makes no sense.

Comment: Please share the sample code using github. Again, Mvc views are not the perfect fit for Angularjs. You just need to use html.